# What is the best way to send a POST request to HTTPS service url, using "application/xml" header and string xml as body?

Tags: java, spring-boot, post, https

**This way didn't work.**

public String sendReqest(String httpsUrl, String xmlRequest) {

```
HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);


HttpEntity<String> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<String>(xmlRequest, httpHeaders);

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
String result = restTemplate.postForObject(httpsUrl, httpEntity, String.class);
return result;
```

}

I get this exception:
**PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target**

Comment: The https service is public? if not do you have the root certificate installed where you run the pring app? or do you have the trustsore of the https certificate?

Comment: Rick, thank you very much for your quick response! I just installed the certificate using the keytool in cacerts file, and it works perfectly. Thanks for your support, really appreciated.